# Css - Bangle shaped curve div/button

Tags: html, css

Need to achieve this using css for a button/div

[image]

Any hints ?

Thanks!

Comment: My bad, although I was asking for hints. Next time, I would certainly put my code down here. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Only css:

```css
button { border: none; background: transparent; cursor: pointer; }
.it {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #db601b;
  border: 2px solid #707f92;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.it.i {
  z-index: 3;
  background: #e9a076;
  border: 2px solid #a78d84;
}


.aver {
  background:#db601b;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 30rem;
  border-left: 2px solid #707f92;
  border-right: 2px solid #707f92;
  margin: -1.7rem 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <div class="it i"></div>
  <div class="aver"></div>
  <div class="it"></div>
</button>
```